# Using heatmap view in custom images JS

Tags: library, javascript, heatmap, image

I'm making a web with angular 9, taking data about pressure sensors in the feet and I would like to have a visual way to represent the data.
I saw some libraries that handle heatmaps like D3.js but I only see examples in tables or in maps.
I'm kinda new in this and I wonder if someone knows the best library to achieve a result like in the photo with my sensors data.

[image]